# How to fix JSONObject cannot convert to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, arraylist, response

Iv'ed try to convert JSONObject into a JSONArray and its make an error for typeMismacth error. i try to figur it out what happens but i stucked on this.

```
private void prepareReportList(String reportList) {
    try {
        JSONObject task_type_list = null;
        try {
            task_type_list = new JSONObject(reportList);
            JSONArray data = task_type_list.getJSONArray("data");

            int length = data.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                addReportData(data.getJSONObject(i));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        setDataValuesToView(caregiverReportList);
    }
}
```

This is my code.

and the response return this output,

```
{
    "data":{
        "c_correctCount":"0",
        "c_total":"0",
        "r_correctCount":"0",
        "r_total":"0",
        "p_correctCount":"0",
        "p_total":"0",
        "i_correctCount":"0",
        "i_total":"0"
    }
}
```

how i fixed this. i need to convert the response into JSONArray. How do implement it.

Comment: *how i fixed this* `data` should be a json array (`[...]`) not a json object (`{...}`) ... (or you sould parse it as object not array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls try below code

```
 private void prepareReportList(String reportList) {
    try {
        JSONObject task_type_list = null;
        try {
            task_type_list = new JSONObject(reportList);

            JSONObject jObjData = task_type_list.getJSONObject("data");
            Iterator iterator = jObjData.keys();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    String key = (String) iterator.next();
                    JSONObject obj = jObjData.getJSONObject(key);
                    addReportData(obj);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        setDataValuesToView(caregiverReportList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't treat **data** element as a JSONArray since its clear that **data** is a collection of an unordered key, value pair with curly braces { }.

If your end goal is to group every two pairs that share the same letter prefix into a JSONObject and wrap them in a JSONArray then you have to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution

```
//this is the jsonobject which is getting from server
JSONObject dataObj= json.getJSONObject("data"); 
Iterator x = dataObj.keys();

//here we are creating jsonArray object
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

//by looping Iterator converting jsonobject to jsonarray
while (x.hasNext()){
String key = (String) x.next();
jsonArray.put(dataObj.get(key));
}
```

If you any doubt ask me, in comment section keep coding :)